Two elliptic curves with the same j-invariants
This is an interesting observation of mine when exploring moduli of elliptic curves. 
Let's fix a base field $k$ and assume that we have two elliptic curves $E$, $E'$ which are isomorphic over $\bar k$, then consider their automorphism groups $G/k$ and $G'/k$, my proposition is $B_kG\cong B_kG'$. 
I would like to verify:

Is my argument correct?
Is this already known in the literature? If so, could someone point me to relevant references?


What is the meaning of $B_kG$? Please mention.

@DEBAJYOTI DE , thanks for pointing out, by B_kG I mean the classifying stack BG over Spec k, parametrizing G-torsors over k in fppf topology. (I think here étale topology is enough)
